# Oracle SQL - seconds between two dates, ignoring a maintenance window

Tags: sql, oracle, date

In my oracle DB, I have a table 'action' containing two columns, start_time and end_time (both date). I can query action duration for each action in seconds like this:

```
select (end_time-start_time)*24*60*60 as actionDuration from action
```

We have a 2 hour maintenance window, 00:00 - 02:00. I'd like to ignore the elapsed time of an action that occurs within this window.

- action may start & end outside of the maint window.
- action may begin & end within the window (ignore these).
- action may begin within the maint window and end outside the maint window. Just the seconds outside the maint window should count.
- action may begin outside but terminate within the main window. Just the seconds outside the maint window should count.

One final complicated case : an action duration may span more than one maint window

Comment: What means "ignore the elapsed time"? If an action intersects with a maintenance, to subtract duration of intersection from duration of an action?

Comment: For your 3rd case, you say that if it begins within the maintenance window, and ends outside that only seconds should count.  If this is true, is the assumption that all actions starting within your maintenance window will never exceed 1 minute?  What about the 5th case where an action can span multiple time windows?  If an action starts within one maintenance window, but ends after say two other maintenance windows, would you really only want seconds to count for that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my guess in comments is correct, then:

```
select a.id, max((end_time - start_time) * 1440) - sum(nvl((mend2 - mbeg2), 0) * 1440) duration
  from (select id, start_time, end_time, mbeg, mend,
               case when start_time between mbeg and mend then start_time else maint.mbeg end mbeg2, 
               case when end_time   between mbeg and mend then end_time   else maint.mend end mend2
          from action a left join 
              (select to_date(:PSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') + rownum - 1 mbeg, 
                      to_date(:PSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') + 2/24 + rownum - 1 mend
                 from dual connect by rownum < :PDAYS) maint
           on (maint.mbeg between start_time and end_time) or (maint.mend between start_time and end_time)
        -- this condition I forgot earlier
        where not (start_time between mbeg and mend 
                   and 
                   end_time   between mbeg and mend)
) a
 group by a.id
 order by a.id;
```

Here you need to use parameters:

- `:PSTART` - date and time of your first maintenance
- `:PDAYS` - count of days of period in which you want to calculate duration of actions

Now query counts durations in minutes, if you need another measurement unit, use another number instead of 1440.

**UPD** How it works.

- Subquery `maint` uses hierarchical clause `connect by` to create as many rows, as you need (equal to count of days from first action to last)
- Then I make left join with tables of action. Join condition - maintenance begins or stops inside an action. Result of join - list of actions, where every action is followed by all its maintenances, and if action don't intersect with maintenance - `NULL`
- Then I shift start or end of maintenance, if it occurs while action take place. If action started during maintenance, then I use start of action as start of maintenance (field `mbeg2`)
- the same thing I do with end of maintenance (field `mend2`); result - fields mbeg2 and mend2 contains intervals when action and maintenance window took place simultaneously (just intersection of periods)
- then I count length of action using `max` aggregate function. if action was very long and intersected with many windows, it will have many lines in subquery, that's why I use `max` (you also can use `min` or `avg` and get the same result).
- then I count sum of all reduced maintenance intervals (results of intersection) and subtract this sum from action length

I hope now it is clear.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Sorry for not making my question clear. Yes, any intersection of action duration and maintenance window can be subtracted for the total duration time.

Comment: I don't understand your SQL. It does work, but if i make the maintenance window an hour longer (so that an action now occurs entirely within the maintenance window, the *whole* action duration is returned.

As the maint window never changes, is it possible to avoid selecting a list of the last 6 days maint windows and instead just compare on the HH24?

Comment: @EHammond "so that an action now occurs entirely within the maintenance window, the whole action duration is returned" Sorry about that, I forgot to add this condition to query (don't count actions if it starts and ends inside one maintenance window). I'll add description to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

This approach could really kill performance if there's a lot of time between the dates, and if you're running a report on multiple records, but might be worth a look. It requires a primary key for the action. I would consider adding a column to your table to store the elapsed time, and calculating it in an update trigger.

Substitute the correct name of your primary key column of course:

```
with action as
(select id, starttime, endtime from action where id = :P_ACTION_ID)
select count(*) seconds from action
where to_number(to_char(starttime + ((level-1) / (24*60*60)) , 'HH24')) between 2 and 23 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (endtime-starttime)*24*60*60;
```

Comment: Thanks Bacs. This works well for a few results, but for the report period I'm interested in, SQL execution duration quickly ramps up from a few seconds to many minutes (as you indicated might happen).

Comment: Yeah, that was always the worry. It's basically generating a record for every second between the two dates, so that's over half a million if the dates are a week apart, which in my test database takes about 4 seconds to run the query. Out of curiosity, what's the biggest report period?

Comment: 7 days by default, though there's a request to allow users to specify a date range and we archive 1 year

Comment: 7 days not so bad if you calculate once and store in the table when `end_time` is updated. 365 days gives me `ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation`. There are definitely better ways to achieve what you need here. Pity, I like my solution, apart from the fact that in the real world it probably won't work!

Answer (score 0):

```
select (- case when start_time > to_date(to_char(start_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '0200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
               then start_time - to_date(to_char(start_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '0200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
               else 0 end
        + case when end_time > to_date(to_char(end_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '0200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
               then end_time - to_date(to_char(end_time, 'YYYYMMDD') || '0200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
               else 0 end      
        + (select sum(case when trunc(start_time) + level - 1/24/60/60 > 
                                to_date(to_char(trunc(start_time) + level - 1/24/60/60, 'YYYYMMDD') || '0200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
                           then trunc(start_time) + level - 1/24/60/60 
                                - to_date(to_char(trunc(start_time) + level - 1/24/60/60, 'YYYYMMDD') || '0200', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI')
                           else 0 end) 
           from dual connect by level <= trunc(end_time) - trunc(start_time)
       )) * 24 * 60 *60 as actionduration 
from action;
```

The idea is to split your interval on smaller intervals:
day first: [00:00, start_time] *(first case with minus sign)*
day last: [00:00, end_time] *(second case)*
days between: [00:00 - 23:59] *(scalar subquery)*

Comment: Thanks for your response. Oracle doesn't like the 'start_time' on line #5. It reports 'invalid identifier'

Comment: @EHammond Yes, it's more the 1 level nesting, I used WITH for tests. I can rewrite this query for one row ACTION table or give me the whole your query

Answer (score 0):

I know I missed the boat on this one, but I put another answer together using a very different approach from my previous answer and may as well post it. It's not as elegant (downright ugly to be honest), but it seems to work and it's extremely fast. The start and end times are manipulated to produce a union of three separate queries - one for whole days, one for the first day, and one for the last day. The whole days can be multiplied by 22 hours (24 minus the maintenance window) to get the seconds. The start and end times are rounded up to 02:00 if necessary for calculating the first and last days.

It takes 1/10 of a second to calculate a period of 10 years. There's no use of `CONNECT BY LEVEL` to generate rows, so the period doesn't really matter.

I'll post as I tested, using records from a dummy CTE:

```
with action as
(select 1 id
       ,to_date('16-nov-2014 01:33:32', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') starttime
       ,to_date('20-nov-2014 14:05:06', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') endtime 
 from dual
 union 
 select 2 id
       ,sysdate starttime
       ,sysdate+365 endtime 
 from dual)
select id, sum(difference) difference from
(select id
      ,(case when endtime between trunc(endtime) 
             and trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
                then trunc(endtime) 
             else endtime 
       end
        -
       case when endtime between trunc(endtime) 
             and trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
                then trunc(endtime) 
             else trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
       end) * 24*60*60 difference
from action
union
select id
      ,(trunc(endtime)-trunc(starttime+1))*22*60*60 difference 
from action
union
select id
      ,(trunc(starttime+1) - case when starttime between trunc(starttime) 
                                   and trunc(starttime) + (2/24) 
                                      then trunc(starttime) + (2/24) 
                                  else starttime 
                             end)*24*60*60 difference
from action)
group by id;
```

Here's a longer version showing the workings out for the three queries:

```
with action as
(select 1 id
       ,to_date('16-nov-2014 01:33:32', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') starttime
       ,to_date('20-nov-2014 14:05:06', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') endtime 
 from dual
 union 
 select 2 id
       ,sysdate starttime
       ,sysdate+3650 endtime 
 from dual)
select id
      ,'Last day part' description
      ,to_char(case when endtime between trunc(endtime) 
                and trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
                 then trunc(endtime) 
                 else trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
               end, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') starttime
      ,to_char(case when endtime between trunc(endtime) 
                and trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
                 then trunc(endtime) 
                 else endtime 
               end, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') endtime
      ,(case when endtime between trunc(endtime) 
             and trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
                then trunc(endtime) 
             else endtime 
       end
        -
       case when endtime between trunc(endtime) 
             and trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
                then trunc(endtime) 
             else trunc(endtime) + (2/24) 
       end) * 24*60*60 difference
from action
union
select id
      ,'Whole days' description
      ,to_char(trunc(starttime+1), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') starttime
      ,to_char(trunc(endtime), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') endtime
      ,(trunc(endtime)-trunc(starttime+1))*22*60*60 difference 
from action
union
select id
      ,'First day part' description
      ,to_char(case when starttime between trunc(starttime) 
                     and trunc(starttime) + (2/24) 
                     then trunc(starttime) + (2/24) 
                     else starttime 
                    end, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') starttime
      ,to_char(trunc(starttime+1), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') endtime
      ,(trunc(starttime+1) - case when starttime between trunc(starttime) 
                                   and trunc(starttime) + (2/24) 
                                      then trunc(starttime) + (2/24) 
                                  else starttime 
                             end)*24*60*60 difference
from action;
```